# Amzon SP-API : repricing using JSON_LISTINGS_FEED in multi-marketplaces with python

Tags: python, amazon-selling-partner-api

I am trying to update prices in multiple marketplaces using PYTHON-AMAZON-SP-API through of API FEED using feedtype = JSON_LISTINGS_FEED.

I tried like it follows, it works fine but i need to spread that price to others marketplaces, how can i achieve that? i must create one feed for each marketplace?

```
feed_json =
{
    "header": {
        "sellerId": "xxxxxx",
        "version": "2.0",
        "issueLocale": "es_ES"
    },
    "messages": [
        {
            "messageId": 1,
            "sku": "SKU-1",
            "operationType": "PARTIAL_UPDATE",
            "productType": "PRODUCT",
            "attributes": {
                "purchasable_offer": [
                    {
                        "our_price": [
                            {
                                "schedule": [
                                    {
                                        "value_with_tax": 100
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        ],
                        "currency": "EUR",
                        "marketplace_id": Marketplaces.ES.marketplace_id
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}
    
    feed_json_str = json.dumps(feed_json)

    feed_json_bytes = BytesIO(bytes(feed_json_str, "utf-8"))

    feed_json_bytes.seek(0)

    try:
        feeds_api = Feeds(credentials=MYCREDENTIALS, marketplace=Marketplaces.ES)

        response = feeds_api.submit_feed(
            "JSON_LISTINGS_FEED", feed_json_bytes, "application/json; charset=UTF-8")
```